# Tool for reading HTML from an HTTPS page in command

Tags: windows, command-line, https

Does anyone know of a tool that allows the code of an HTTPS file to be displayed in(or dumped from) command or something similar.

Essentially, I'm trying to monitor an https web site for a certain snippet of code condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two popular command-line tools that do this, wget and curl.  Either should do what you want.  They are both freely available for Unix, Linux and Windows.

Curl: http://curl.haxx.se/

Wget: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/